# How can the below line be replaced in .net4.0

Tags: .net-4.0, .net-4.5, asp.net-4.0, asp.net-4.5

How can I write below line of code in .net 4.0:

```
EventHandlerTaskAsyncHelper asyncHelper = new EventHandlerTaskAsyncHelper(WriteLogMessages);--> this is in .net 4.5
```

Thanks

Comment: Install .NET 4.5 perhaps?

Comment: If that's the only line of code that's causing you issues, you might want to consider just grabbing the implementation from the [Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/EventHandlerTaskAsyncHelper.cs,0009fd6522687b6c). However, I'd suspect that this is actually just the tip of the iceberg in trying to back-convert some .NET 4.5 code to 4.0.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'am building the app in .net 4.0 that was used in .net 4.5 .. @leppie

Comment: type or namespace task eventhandler could not be found.. I'am getting this error. How can I solve this? @Damien_The_Unbeliever

Comment: What are you trying to do? You can't just take code that uses features found in .NET 4.5 and expect it to run in 4.0. You *may* be able to bypass using the `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` package, but the real solution is to upgrade your code to 4.5

Answer (score 1):

EventHandlerTaskAsyncHelper is simply a helper that provides an APM-style (BeginOperation/EndOperation) interface over a Task. A Task *does* implement IAsyncResult so you can return it directly from a `BeginOperation` method. The `EndOperation` method only has to cast its `IAsyncResult` argument back to a Task and await it. This is shown in the MSDN article 
[TPL and Traditional .NET Framework Asynchronous Programming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997423%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#sectionToggle7):

```
 public IAsyncResult BeginCalculate(int decimalPlaces, AsyncCallback ac, object state)
{
    Task<string> f = Task<string>.Factory.StartNew(_ => Compute(decimalPlaces), state);
    if (ac != null) f.ContinueWith((res) => ac(f));
    return f;
}

public string Compute(int numPlaces)
{
    ...
}

public string EndCalculate(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    return ((Task<string>)ar).Result;
}
```

The EventHandlerTaskAsyncHelper class <strike>just</strike> makes it easier to write such code, with some checks for already completed tasks etc. The concept isn't something specific to .NET 4.5.

That said, the best solution would be to upgrade the rest of your code to .NET 4.5, not try to backport the application to .NET 4.0. While you *can* get some of the 4.5 functionality with the [Microsoft.Bcl.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/) package, significant parts will be missing. Newer libraries like TPL Dataflow, Immutable Collections etc simply require .NET 4.5 to work.

Unless you target Windows XP there is no reason to remain in .NET 4.0, especially when the application is already written in 4.5.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem of such migration is that you are trying to fit into architecture solution available only in .NET 4.5. According MSDN, [`EventHandlerTaskAsyncHelper`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.eventhandlertaskasynchelper.aspx) the only purpose is:

> > Converts task-returning asynchronous methods into methods that use the asynchronous programming model used in previous versions of ASP.NET and that is based on begin and end events.

And Remarks section:

> > To handle asynchronous tasks in ASP.NET 4.5, you implement the logic to return a task as a TaskEventHandler delegate. **This model of asynchronous task-based programming supersedes the model used in previous versions of ASP.NET**, which bases all event handling on begin and end events. ...

So this class is used for the wrapping other code to fit into the new version of ASSP.NET MVC site. Thus you have to reconsider the whole class diagram and architecture of your application according rules of the MVC version you'll be using in your project.

May be this thread will be a good start:

[ASP.NET MVC - IHttpModule, Asynchronous Event Handler, EventHandlerTaskAsyncHelper](http://www.brainthud.com/cards/5218/24643/how-do-you-create-an-asynchronous-http-module)

Comment: Threee issues with this answer - Tasks were introduced in .NET 4.0 and articles on how to convert the APM style to/from Tasks were published from the start. The Parallel Extensions library contains extensions and helpers for many common classes like Smtp, WebRequest etc and was probably the origin of EventHandlerTaskAsyncHelper. Second, ASP.NET was never mentioned. Third, the link only shows an example of how to use EventHandlerTaskAsyncHelper

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos 1. EventHandlerTaskAsyncHelper is being used in ASP.NET 4.5, its namespace is System.Web, as I've linked, and it is not a part of parallel extensions. 2. I can't understand why are you talking about Tasks, as they aren't mentioned at all. 3. Link is about the implementing the `IHTTPModule` which can be point of interest for the OP, as I don't know what exactly he wants to do.

Comment: Oops, didn't check the namespace, but the functionality isn't specific to ASP.NET. It's a generic implementation of calling Begin/End methods from Tasks, similar to the [MSDN samples for .NET 4.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997423%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#sectionToggle7). If I were the OP I'd be more concerned with the 4.5 Web features missing, not the helper implementation